# How to remove a field in the form twig in Drupal 8?

Tags: forms, twig, drupal-8

In Drupal 8, the form twig is like that :

```html
<form{{ attributes }}>
  {{ children }}
</form>
```

I would like display all fields exept one.
Usually we use the `without` filter but `children` is a string so that won't work.

```html
<form{{ attributes }}>
  {{ children|without('unwanted') }}
</form>
```

In the form twig, we can access to the `element` variable which is an array. But still, the without filter doesn't work here.

```html
<form{{ attributes }}>
 {{ element|without('unwanted') }}
</form>
```

I know I can display all the fields 1 by 1 with `{{ element.field }}`, But if my form has new fields they will not be printed until I update the form twig. I want to keep the dynamical purpose.

> I **do not** want to update the form code in php to keep the layout in twig.

Any idea ?

Comment: Try disabling the field in the manage form display option ? or can add hidden attribute to the field?

Comment: It is a custom form, there is no admin interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found a quite good answer :

1. Create the custom template

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 *
 * Available variables
 * - form
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_mycustomform()
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
#}
{{ form }}
```

2. Declare the template in the theme function

```
'mycustomform' => [
  'render element' => 'form',
],
```

3. Apply the template to the form

```
$form['#theme'] = 'mycustomform';
```

### Result : In the new template, we can use the `without` twig  function

```
{{ form|without('myfield') }}
```

## Edit 2023

Maybe a simpler solution :

```html
    <div class="fr-mb-2w">
      <div class="fr-grid-row  fr-grid-row--gutters">
        <div class="fr-col fr-col-md-6">{{ element.email }}</div>
        <div class="fr-col fr-col-md-6">{{ element.profile }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    {# Display all other fields. #}
    {% for name in element|keys %}
      {% if not (name starts with '#' or name in ['email', 'profile', 'actions']) %}
        {{ element[name] }}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Also see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/245127/how-to-render-specific-form-elements-from-the-theme-file

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{% for key in element|keys %}
    {{ children|without(key) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope that works out...

Comment: Children is not an array, so without doesn't work on it.